# signmessage and verifymessage CLI commands not accepting Address from getnewaddress?

Tags: address, bitcoin-cli, message-signing, cli

I am trying the following commands on my v0.19.0.1 Core implementation:
`CLI signmessage $(CLI getnewaddress) <message>`
and the identical
`CLI signmessagewithprivkey $(bitcoin-cli dumpprivkey $(CLI getnewaddress)) <message>`

Both times I get Error code: -3 "Address does not refer to key"
All my addresses are wrapped-Segwit (3...). Does this mean since its P2SH there is no way to find the privkey from the address?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`signmessage` and `verifymessage` only work with legacy type addresses. They do not work with segwit addresses. There is ongoing work to introduce a new message signing standard that will work regardless of address type.

Some discussion about why they only work on legacy addresses can be found in this issue: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/10542

Comment: Is there a way for me to request legacy addresses from my wallet?

Comment: `getnewaddress "" legacy`

Answer (score 1):

Use `signmessagewithprivkey` for non legacy addresses.