# Signmessage with Raspiblitz

Tags: taproot, message-signing, raspberry-pi

For an absolute beginner, how do I sign the new adress formats (taproot e.g.)? In Ride the Lightning (RTL) there is the possiblity to sign messages for lightning.

But I need to sign from a specific onchain adress. I also tried `bitcoin-cli signmessage <adr> <msg>` but this did neither work for a taproot adress nor for a Bech32 address (both generated from RTL).

The error message returned is

```
error code: -32601
error message:
Method not found
```

which somehow seems like the signmessage command is unkown?

I also found [this](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/98518/signmessage-and-verifymessage-cli-commands-not-accepting-address-from-getnewaddr) thread. However I am currently unaware where to get the private key from for the suggested solution `signmessagewithprivkey`

I tried `bitcoin-cli dumpprivkey <adr>` which resulted in the same error as above (Method not found).

Answer (score 1):

Solved it with the help of the support of Pocket Bitcoin. T
Get the Adress you want to sign with, I used the RTL interface to generate a new onchain adress but you can also use

```
lncli wallet addresses list
```

Be wary though this might entail already used adress so first confirm that you are not reusing an address you already used in the past (you can e.g. verify via mempool.space)

Signing itself is then very easy via.

```
lncli wallet addresses signmessage --address <enteradreee> --msg <msg>
```